# How to find duplicates where multiple columns match

Tags: mysql

I'd like to find dublicates in a table where X, Y, and Z matches, to finally clean the old one which is identified by a timestamp.

```
+------------+-----+----+-----+
| Created    | X   | Y  | Z   | 
+------------+-----+----+-----+
| 1515622543 | 334 | 72 | 269 |
| 1515622544 | 334 | 72 | 270 | 
| 1515622601 | 334 | 72 | 268 | 
| 1515622953 | 334 | 72 | 268 | 
+------------+-----+----+-----+
```

In this example there is an dublicate at `X=334, Y=72, Z=268`. I would like to list them - so it finally looks like:

```
+------------+-----+----+-----+
| 1515622601 | 334 | 72 | 268 | 
| 1515622953 | 334 | 72 | 268 | 
+------------+-----+----+-----+
```

**Already tried:**

`select count(distinct X), count(distinct Y), count(distinct Z) from decayworld;`
 - which just counts and do not show me where ALL 3 (X,Y,Z) matches.

`SELECT X, Y, Z, COUNT(*) FROM decayworld GROUP BY X, Y, Z HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
+-----+----+-----+----------+
| X   | Y  | Z   | COUNT(*) |
+-----+----+-----+----------+
| 334 | 72 | 268 |        2 |
+-----+----+-----+----------+`
 - it counts the results, but not list them.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Tried some code with `COUNT`, but ya it just counts the entries - actually need an beginning to find a way.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Added my tried code.

Comment: Try to use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @clinomaniac Why?

Comment: @Strawberry This is what I am thinking...`SELECT X, Y, Z, COUNT(*)
FROM table GROUP BY X, Y, Z HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to get all the duplicates. Is that not right?

Comment: Added ur result to question.

Comment: What do you mean counts the results but not lists them? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Adding this to my question to explain it :)

Comment: you're so close!

Comment: What's the expected behaviour when there are three or more duplicates? That will have bearing on the correct query

Comment: @e_i_pi may u can help me [here](http://rextester.com/NITZC10097) to find an answer. How to finally delete ALL older ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the OP wants to delete *all* of the older records (which was stipulated in the comments after the original question was asked), this query gives that outcome. This solution is assuming that the column `id` is unique and sorted ascending from oldest to newest:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable GROUP BY x, y, z
    ) AS keepers
    WHERE keepers.id = mytable.id
);
```

[Rextester link](http://rextester.com/ZVGR71004)

Comment: Like said before I opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197274/how-to-find-duplicates-where-multiple-columns-match/48197998#48197998) where I explained it more and found new problems, but I am really thankful for that reply.

Comment: The thing is that if there are 2 events (or even 10) at the same coords and the same time, all of them gets deleted. It should delete the `break` events and left the newest `place` column (and if there is let's say 3 times the newest place column, left one as result). Check the problem out [here](http://rextester.com/MVF12117).

Comment: @johnmiles33 I'm not sure I understand you properly, and it sounds like there's some scope creep here. If your new problem is significantly different in any way, it's best you ask a new question, so that the answer is tailored to your exact problem.

Comment: To my mind, this is more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

You are getting close to an answer by using `count()`

You should `group` your results, or select distinct in order to get duplicates.  Then use a `having` clause to filter for only dupes

Once you have that, join back to your table to get the IDs

Don't use `Table` as a table name, it's a reserved word

```
#test for a temp table for your dupes
select x,y,z, count(*) from mytable group by x, y, z having count(*) >1;

#one type of solution to find your IDs
select mytable.id, dupes.* from 
(select x,y,z, count(*) from mytable group by x, y, z having count(*) >1) dupes
left join mytable on mytable.x = dupes.x and mytable.y = dupes.y and mytable.z = dupes.z
;
```

[Sample](http://rextester.com/TATGE2843) in Rextester

You can get different output, whatever kind you like messing with the above

Comment: Works rly good. Is there any easy way according to your code to delete the older one of the duplicates?

Comment: @johnmiles33 definitely!  This would be a great opportunity for you to ask another question.  You already have the sample data set and your query.  You can try some delete statements in rextester and if you can't figure it out, as a question and the community can help!

Comment: I will :) Shortened it a bit [here](http://rextester.com/NITZC10097), may u can help before I open a new extra question for it.

Comment: would really require a question though.  would need more info.  For example, everyone else is answering deleting the minimum ID; but you need to specify, are you deleting first/last.  are there situations where there could be dozens of dupes?  which ones do you want to get rid of?

Comment: I prepared a new question - just wait until I can post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY to get counts for matching columns.

In this case, the query will be something like:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, COUNT(*)
FROM decayworld
GROUP BY X, Y, Z;
```

This will give all rows that have the same values for X, Y, Z and their counts. To get Minimum Ids for each row, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z, COUNT(*), MIN(Created)
FROM decayworld
GROUP BY X, Y, Z;
```

Keep in mind that this will only work for duplicates that have two rows only. To delete the duplicates, you can select all rows with MAX ids and delete the rest. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f85e0f/3

Query just to get MIN(created)

```
SELECT MIN(created)
FROM `events`
GROUP BY X, Y, Z
HAVING COUNT(created)>1
```

And if you want to delete them:

```
DELETE e FROM `events` e
JOIN (SELECT MIN(created) to_delete
FROM `events`
GROUP BY X, Y, Z
HAVING COUNT(created)>1) d
ON e.created = d.to_delete
```

Comment: Don't we need to change it to `JOIN (SELECT MAX(created) to_delete` and finally delete these results to get the one newest of the duplicates left?

Comment: In your initial post you wrote **Next step will be to delete the older one** so you tell me what behavior do you expect

Comment: You are right with this point. I didn't thought about how to get this in one query. Your answer is totally correct according to my question, so for the other problem I will open a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

As Test to see what would be deleted:

```
select not_keep_rows.*
from your_table as not_keep_rows
   inner join (
      select MIN(created) as min_date
      from your_table
      group by x,y,z
      having count(*) > 1
   ) as keep_rows on keep_rows.min_date = not_keep_rows.created
```

Actual execution of delete

```
delete not_keep_rows.*
from your_table as not_keep_rows
   inner join (
      select MIN(created) as min_date
      from your_table
      group by x,y,z
      having count(*) > 1
   ) as keep_rows on keep_rows.min_date = not_keep_rows.created
```