# Advanced duplicate deletion

Tags: mysql

Part 1 of the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197274/how-to-find-duplicates-where-multiple-columns-match). I now like to delete specific older records.

**Short story:** We got coordinates, events and timestamps. The goal is to delete the older event on the same coordinates.

The problem is demonstrated [on rextester](http://rextester.com/MVF12117).

```
#build dataset 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, EventName varchar(255), x int, y int, z int, Cause varchar(255));
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
( 1515622543 , 'break' , 334 , 72 , 269 , NULL  ),
( 1515622544 , 'break' , 334 , 72 , 270 , NULL  ),
( 1515622600 , 'break' , 333 , 72 , 269 , NULL  ),
( 1515622601 , 'break' , 333 , 72 , 270 , NULL  ),
( 1515622601 , 'break' , 333 , 73 , 270 , NULL  ),
( 1515622601 , 'break' , 334 , 72 , 268 , NULL  ),
( 1515622953 , 'place' , 334 , 72 , 268 , NULL  ),
( 1515629278 , 'break' , 334 , 72 , 268 , NULL  ),
( 1515629278 , 'place' , 334 , 72 , 268 , NULL  ),
( 1515629480 , 'place' , 333 , 72 , 269 , NULL  ),
( 1515629480 , 'break' , 333 , 72 , 269 , NULL  ),
( 1515629481 , 'place' , 333 , 72 , 269 , NULL  );

DELETE FROM mytable WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM mytable GROUP BY x, y, z
    ) AS keepers
    WHERE keepers.id = mytable.id
);

SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Dozens of duplicates are possible. The older ones are identified by an timestamp. The thing is that if there are 2 events (or even 10) at the same coords and the same time, all of them gets deleted. It should delete the `break` events first and then left the newest `place` event (and if there is let's say 3 times the newest place event, left one of them).

Comment: What should the result set look like (in other words, the data set AFTER the DELETE)